# haskell error parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)

Tags: haskell

this is my code

```
font a = let x= ord a in
        if x>=0 || x<=31 || x>=126 then ["*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****"]
        else
            auxfont (fontBitmap!!(x-32))
            where
            auxfont b = let y = map trns (map rInt (map show b)) in
                       convertir y []
            trns z = modA [] 1 z
            modA o l k
                  | l < 8 = modA (o++[(k `mod` 2)]) (l+1) (k `div` 2) 
                  | otherwise o           
            convertir (e1:e2:e3:e4:e5) f 
                  | e1==[]  = f
                  | otherwise convertir [tail(e1),tail(e2),tail(e3),tail(e4),tail(e5)] (f++[(psr(head(e1)))++(psr(head(e2)))++(psr(head(e3)))++(psr(head(e4)))++(psr(head(e5)))])
            psr 0 = " "
            psr 1 = "*"
```

and i had and this error in convertir:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Pixels           ( Pixels.hs, interpreted )

Pixels.hs:122:13: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: You need an `=` after `otherwise`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why the error**

Every (normal) guard is of the form

```
    | boolean expression = value
```

You missed this out for your `otherwise` cases. It works like this because `otherwise` is defined as

```
otherwise = True
```

so it's not a keyword like `else`, it's just a human-readable "always", and since the guards are tried top-to-bottom, this is a catch-all for anything that wasn't true above.

**Some corrections**

```
font a = let x= ord a in
        if x>=0 || x<=31 || x>=126 then ["*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****"]
        else
            auxfont (fontBitmap!!(x-32))
          where
            auxfont b = let y = map trns (map rInt (map show b)) in
                       convertir y []
            trns z = modA [] 1 z
            modA o l k
                  | l < 8 = modA (o++[(k `mod` 2)]) (l+1) (k `div` 2)
```

here:

```
              | otherwise = o       -- added =
        convertir (e1:e2:e3:e4:e5) f 
              | e1==[]  = f
```

and here:

```
              | otherwise = convertir [tail(e1),tail(e2),tail(e3),tail(e4),tail(e5)] (f++[(psr(head(e1)))++(psr(head(e2)))++(psr(head(e3)))++(psr(head(e4)))++(psr(head(e5)))])
        psr 0 = " "
        psr 1 = "*"
```

**Some abbreviations**

By the way,

- `["*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****","*****"]` is `replicate 7 "*****"` and
- `map trns (map rInt (map show b))` is `map (trns.fInt.show) b`.
- Also `[tail(e1),tail(e2),tail(e3),tail(e4)]` is `map tail [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5]`
- but I think you have a type error with `:e5`, because it has to be a list of lists in the pattern `(e1:e2:e3:e4:e5)` but you've used it like an element `tail(e5)`.
- Also `[(psr(head(e1)))++(psr(head(e2)))++(psr(head(e3)))++(psr(head(e4)))++(psr(head(e5)))]` is `map (psr.head) [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5]`.